# Excel - compare text from 2 ranges using nested loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, nested-loops

I'm trying to loop through 2 Excel ranges and compare the text from cell A in workbook A to cell A in workbook B and so on. If the text matches, I'm then setting variables that equal the column numbers from each workbook.

```
For Each cell In xl.Workbooks(MyWB).Sheets("Exports").Range("D2:J2")
   For Each c In xl.Workbooks(TempWB).Sheets("TempExports").Range("D1:J1")
```

I'm having trouble with my nested loop. The second line above is throwing a type mismatch, but why? And what can I do to solve this? If I remember right the above syntax works in VBA so I anticipated it would work the same in .NET, but apparently that's not the case. Any suggestions? I'm using VB.NET with WinForms.

Here's some code with a little more detail

```
    For Each cell In xl.Workbooks(MyWB).Sheets("Exports").Range("D2:J2")
        For Each c In xl.Workbooks(TempWB).Sheets("TempExports").Range("D1:J1")
            If c.Text = cell.Text Then
                MyWBColumn = cell.Column
                tempWBColumn = c.Column
                GetColumnLetterMyWB(MyWBColumn)
                GetColumnLetterTempWB(TempWBColumn)
                xl.Workbooks(MyWB).Sheets("Exports").Range(ColumnLetterMyWB & "3:" & GetColumnLetterMyWB & (RowCount + 1)).Value = _
                xl.Workbooks(TempWB).Sheets("TempExports").Range(TempWBColumnLetter & "2:" & ColumnLetterTempWB & (RowCount)).Value

            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: `Option Strict On` will allow VS to help catch this kind of error

Comment: Option Strict creates late binding errors when using Excel interop